# Draggable containment alternative

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using 2 divs that I can drag em in same container.
For example I have left float div1 and right float div2 which are in divC container.
They can drag only horizontally left and right. But the right float div2 should not pass over left side of div1.

```
<div id="divC">
    <div id="startpx" style="float:left;"></div>
    <div id="div1" style="float:left"></div>
    <div id="div2" style="float:right;"></div>
    <div id="endpx" style="float:right;"></div>
</div>
```

I am using startpx and endpx as divs that will show me the px of the something-o-meter that I am developing right now.

When I add another div that will refresh his position while the div1 is moving (in drag function), and also will be the containment of div2.
Yes it worked out, but this solution isn't the right one for me since the main containment is moving div2 while i am moving div1.

Is there any other alternative that will be a solution for this problem, or there is still way that I can do it with containment parameter of draggable or any other trick or magic from draggable.

Comment: Could you create a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: I found the solution in http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range , the same thing I wanted to do, is already done by jqueryui and its called range slider.